# RANK repeating data set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Assuming that I have data like the ones in columns A and B, how can I rank them like column C?  I have tried multiple varieties of `RANK` and `NTILE` but have been unsuccessful.  Thank you.

[image]

Note:  There are not always 3 rows for each group, it varies.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables are inherently unordered.  There is no distinguishing between the 1st and 4th row, with the data as you've presented.  You can generate an equivalent result set, but the ordering may differ.

Simple arithmetic may do the trick:

```
select a, 
       ( row_number() over (order by a) + 2) / 3 ) as 
from t
order by a, b, c;
```

A better method uses the `b` column:

```
select a,
       row_number() over (partition by b order by a) as c
from t
order by a, c;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I should have mentioned that the break is not always at 3.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Also, tried the second approach and it ranks everything as 1, since the numbers are ever changing in column b.

Comment: @ASQLDBA . . . In your example, the numbers repeat.  If you have a different question, you should ask it as a different question, providing appropriate sample data and desired results in the question.

Comment: are you upset that my example didn't show varying number of rows and that I  forgot to mention that such a scenario exists?  The sample data and desired results are fine.

Comment: @ASQLDBA . . . Your sample data has a very strong pattern that implies what you are looking for.  It seems highly misleading with regard to your actual problem.  If you revise the question, you are likely to invalidate the answers of people who have tried to help you -- and that can lead to downvotes.  The best option is to ask another question that more closely resembles what you are trying to do.  The correct word in English would be "disappointed".  Questions should reflect what the questioner is really looking for.

Comment: What Gordon is saying @ASQLDBA  is that you need to provide a complete, verifiable example. If you read the help pages on stack overflow, especially the part about how to ask a good question, you'll understand this. You also get a badge for reading it!

Comment: Bunch of very sensitive people on this board.  Second question and second sensitive, egotistical people to deal with.  Never mind, will ask on another forum.  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ntile as below:

```
Select *, ntile(2) over(order by (Select NULL)) from #data
```

Instead of (Select NULL) you can provide any other valid ordering column based on your data

Comment: Thank you very much Kannan.  I get an error, because I have to have multiple columns instead of NULL and SQL Server throws an error.

What I am trying to do is run a query on the job server that lists the job_id, step_id, and run_date (using the agent_datetime function).  Then I want to group each run of the job, so if my job runs once an hour, the first time it runs, the rank should be 1 for all steps, 2 for second run, and so on.